# Access to Barclays.net (Banking )

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

Currently using IE to access https://cashmanagement.barclays.net/bnetservices/login.aspx and logging in via "Smart Card" However, due to migrations we need to use either Chrome, Edge or FireFox. Now...

The issue is when using any other browser than IE I am unable to login to https://cashmanagement.barclays.net/bnetservices/login.aspx using Smart Card because the "Login" button is missing and just appears as a jigsaw.

How do I resolve this and allow access again.

Comment: If their website is broken on other browsers you need to complain to Barclays.

Comment: Any blocked pop-ups? If you right-click the 'jigsaw' does it offer to install anything? It may well be Flash or Silverlight, which are no longer supported. As David has said, you need to speak to Barclays business support to ask them how to use Chrome or Edge with your smart card reader.

Comment: All login methods supported by Barclays require additional software on your PC. Is this software installed and up-to-date?

Comment: It seems that page is being retired and you should be changing over. From https://cashmanagement.barclays.net/bnetservices/login.aspx "Please be aware that from October we will start redirecting Corporate Bank users to Barclays iPortal after logging in via this page. You will be able to access Barclays.Net from the single sign on link in Barclays iPortal.
For any users that have not yet been redirected, you will need to prepare to login via Barclays iPortal for access to Barclays.Net as well as a range of current and future functionality. This login page will be removed in future. "

Comment: According to that page you should be switching over to use https://iportal.barclays.com/

Comment: I would also install their signing application

Comment: Assuming the smartcard is usb based, it sounds like the you have configure the browser to block all usb devices, as such, it does not see the smartcard device.